# Page Load Not Hit During Dynamic User Control Creation (Web Forms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an issue with programatically created user controls.

From my tests, adding a user control to another control's collection kicks off the user
control's lifecycle.  Specifically, it calls the controls `Page_Load` method.  Does anyone know if there is a way to kick off the
lifecycle of a user control BEFORE a call to the Controls.Add() method is
made?

**Default.aspx code**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder1 ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var module = LoadControl("~/Module.ascx") as Module;

    // If this line of code does not execute, the Page_Load method never executes in the user control.
    //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(module);
}
```

**Module.ascx code**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.DataItem %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater1.DataSource = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I get the feeling that you are trying to work around an issue on how you structured your code.  Other than making the calls into the control yourself I don't see many options.  Could you explain the actual issue you have?

Comment: The example code I supplied is a simplified version of my real problem. I'm trying to create a Telerik RadDock in a user control instead of doing it in the code-behind for the aspx page. The RadDockZone can only contain controls of type RadDock, so I created a  user control and now I'm trying to load the user control and then add the RadDock in the user control to the RadDockZone.Docks collection. What I'm stumped on is why LoadControl() doesn't invoke the control's life cycle events and Controls.Add() does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research, there is no way to trigger a control's life cycle events using the LoadControl() method. The workaround is to create a public method called Initialize() like so:

```
var module = Page.LoadControl("~/Module.ascx") as Module;
module.Initialize();
```

In the Initialize() method, any functionality that would be done in the Page_Load event can be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms178472.aspx#catch_up_events_for_added_controls

For dynamically loaded controls, their events have to be "caught up".

But on the other hand, why would you care whether page_load occurs before or after it's added to the page's control collections?   What is the unwanted result from this?

Comment: Right; you basically should *not* write code which relies on things like that.

Comment: The user control's life cycle events don't get invoked when the LoadControl() method is called. I've placed a breakpoint on the Page_Load event and it never gets hit unless I use the Controls.Add() method. Why don't they get invoked in the LoadControl() method?

Comment: From here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol.aspx we read, "When you load a control into a container control, the container raises all of the added control's events..." I'm wondering if it's possible to raise the control's events manually instead of having to add it to a container control.